# what is the difference between kind, type and sort

Tags: meaning, difference

I see these sentences:

> Newton invented a new type of microscope.
>   Newton invented a new kind of mathematics.
>   Apple invented a new sort of cameras.

What is the difference between *kind*, *sort*, and *type*?

Comment: Did you look what a dictionary says about those words? If you did, what exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: yes i did, it says the same meaning, but i wanna know the context of using them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any clear difference between them. They're synonyms.

"Sort" is somewhat informal when used with this meaning.

Answer (score 2):

*Type* means "a kind or sort"; *sort* is synonym of *kind*.

Notice that "a sort of" as in "They're a sort of greenish-blue colour." or "I had a sort of feeling that she wouldn't come." has a different meaning.

Comment: I'd expect, in your "Notice that" example, to see it phrased as "It is sort of a greenish-blue color."  "kind of" would also work here, but "type of" would definitely not; this phrasing illustrates that they are different parts of speech.

Comment: Actually, the example given from the OALD is "They're a sort of greenish-blue colour." It was me who changed the plural subject with the singular.

Comment: Singular or plural subject makes no difference here; in my idiolect (grew up mid-Atlantic coast, U.S., a *long* time ago, and have lived in New England more than 50 years), it's the position of the "a" that is different.  Regardless, while "sort" or "kind" are both okay in either of these variations, "type" is not.  "Type" just doesn't work with colors; better with objects, like toasters.

Comment: Changing _they_ with _it_ probably didn't make any difference, but replacing _colour_ with _color_ probably changed something. `:)` Those are the examples given for the idiom "a sort of something" that is said to be "used for describing something in a not very exact way." I just wanted to point there are chances that "a sort of" could be used with a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

There are different **types** of **people** ,what *type* of *person* are you ?
There are different kinds of fishes ,what kind of fish do you like to eat ?